# PostgreSQL - Percentage Count

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(eaa.cd_aluno), c.nome_curso FROM evento_atividade_aluno eaa
JOIN aluno a ON eaa.cd_aluno = a.cd_aluno
JOIN curso c ON a.cd_curso_aluno = c.cd_curso
WHERE cd_evento_atividade = 1 AND bln_presenca IS TRUE
GROUP BY c.nome_curso
ORDER BY COUNT(eaa.cd_aluno)
```

And result:

```
1,TESTE 1
2,TESTE 2
3,TESTE 3
```

But I need the results to be like this (In percentage):

```
16.7,TESTE 1
33.3,TESTE 2
50,TESTE 3
```

I tried to do some subqueries but isn't working:

```
SELECT COUNT(eaa.cd_aluno) / (SELECT COUNT(cd_aluno) FROM 
evento_atividade_aluno WHERE cd_evento_atividade = 1 AND bln_presenca IS 
TRUE), c.nome_curso FROM evento_atividade_aluno eaa
JOIN aluno a ON eaa.cd_aluno = a.cd_aluno
JOIN curso c ON a.cd_curso_aluno = c.cd_curso
WHERE cd_evento_atividade = 1 AND bln_presenca IS TRUE
GROUP BY c.nome_curso
ORDER BY COUNT(eaa.cd_aluno)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the query in a derived table and calculate total sum and percentages in an outer query. Use `sum()` as a window function rather than a regular aggregate, so you don't have to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT round(count* 100.0/sum(count) OVER (), 2) AS percent, nome_curso
FROM (
    -- place your query here
    -- instead of VALUES below
    VALUES
        (1, 'TESTE 1'),
        (2, 'TESTE 2'),
        (3, 'TESTE 3')
    ) v (count, nome_curso)

 percent | nome_curso 
---------+------------
   16.67 | TESTE 1
   33.33 | TESTE 2
   50.00 | TESTE 3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I can't check your solution right now, gonna do as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), c.nome_curso,
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM evento_atividade_aluno eaa JOIN
     aluno a
     ON eaa.cd_aluno = a.cd_aluno JOIN
     curso c
     ON a.cd_curso_aluno = c.cd_curso
WHERE cd_evento_atividade = 1 AND bln_presenca IS TRUE
GROUP BY c.nome_curso
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```